# How to get Bot Framework bot published to Skype when pending review for weeks

Tags: botframework

I submitted my Microsoft Bot Framework bot named 3D to be published to Skype a couple of weeks ago. It still says Pending Review and I haven't received any emails. How do I get it published or get a response from Microsoft?

Comment: aren't bots published to the Skype connector by default?

Comment: you can chat with the bot directly via a link, but it's not in the published Skype bot directory. The "published" switch is turned off beside the Skype channel in Azure Portal. When I submit it to publish it, then it says "awaiting review" for a couple of weeks now.

Comment: Try asking the question on https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder

Comment: Thanks. Asked but no reply.

Comment: You still chat with bot via direct link skype or facebook messenge without published. My bot got published after 2 months reviews, so you can wait.